# not able to get the value from the array

Tags: php

I am passing the `oid` in the URL i want to display the data regarding the `oid` passed,but i am not able to get display the value from the function ,it shows error can any one help me ,i new to php

I want to displays a list of orders and shows the order details on the products.php page

i am getting error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: cur_order in C:\wamp\www\var\flagprice\de\lib_products.php on line 50

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\var\flagprice\de\products.php on line 46
```

Here is my code links

[index.php](http://pastebin.com/cf0zmwCy)

[product.php](http://pastebin.com/WgLBuguz)

[lib_util.php](http://pastebin.com/WYpptVnx)

[lib_products.php](http://pastebin.com/wKN4VfRW)

Comment: just use `$_GET['oid']`

Comment: You shouldn't give links to your source code... You should try to reduce your use case as much as you can, and then post it in the question...

Comment: @MuhammadHaseebKhan links are working

Comment: What error is being shown?

Comment: @ jnunez error: `Notice: Undefined variable: cur_order in C:\wamp\www\var\flagprice\de\lib_products.php on line 50 ,Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\var\flagprice\de\products.php on line 46`

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything with the $order_id the loadOrderDetails method:

```
function loadOrderDetails($order_id) {
    $orders    = getOrderInfo();
    $products  = getProducts();
    $customer  = getCustomerInfo();
    $address   = getAddresses();


    return $cur_order;
}
```

Also you are not creating / filling a $cur_order variable.

Maybe you want to do this? (example)

```
function loadOrderDetails($order_id) {
    $cur_order = array();

    $cur_order['orderinfo'] = getOrderInfo($order_id);
    $cur_order['products']  = getProducts($order_id);
    $cur_order['customer']  = getCustomerInfo($order_id);
    $cur_order['address']   = getAddresses($order_id);

    return $cur_order;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,i tried same in your example but its same error

Comment: The first error you will not receive anymore. I defined $cur_order, so it will not give "Undefined variable". We don't have the code for "products.php" where the other error is. So we cannot see what you are accessing there.